Не работает position:fixed;
Присвоил элементу position: fixed, а он не остается на месте а прокручивается вместе со страницей. Очень прошу прощения за большой CSS, только что вставил сюда на проверку фрагмент кода, работает, а если весь CSS то не работает. И не могу найти где ошибка, прошу помочь специалистов/знатоков. Высота call_box чисто проверочная.
CSS


* {
  font-family: Unageo-Medium;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }

}

body {
  opacity: 0;
}

.background {
  background-color: #BFB9B1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bar {
  transition: none;
  background-color: #3A4429;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  animation-duration: 0ms;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.bar h3{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #ddd6ce;
  padding: 1%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}

.bar h3:hover{
  background-color: #687a49;
}

.barMain {
  margin-top: 5%;
  background-color: #3A4429;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.topBar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  nav-up: auto;
  background-color: #3A4429;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 5px 0;
  z-index: 100000;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ddd6ce;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.fixed_down {
  top: 0;
}

.fixed_up {
  top: -75;
}

.topContent {
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  display: flex;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Unageo-Medium";
  src: url(../fonts/Unageo-Medium.ttf);
}

a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  color: #ddd6ce;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mainBody {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
}
.mainBody1 {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
}

.mainText {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.menuButt {
  align-self: center;
  width: max-content;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #3A4429;
  color: #ddd6ce;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  font-size: x-large;
}

.bottomBar {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3A4429;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.iconBottom {
  width: 30px;
}

.textBottom {
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.boxBottom {
  margin-left: 2%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.call_butt{
  background-color: #3A4429;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.call_box {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

/*Carousel*/

.slider {
  width: 39%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 1%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: rotate(2deg);
  border: 4px dashed black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 28px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.slider .list {
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  transition: 1s;
}

.slider .list img {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  object-position: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 114px -19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 114px -19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 114px -19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)
}

.slider .list span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  text-shadow: 4px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition-delay: 2s;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  color: #ddd6ce;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: xx-large;
  z-index: 100;
}

.slider .buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left {
  margin-left: -4%;
  text-shadow: 4px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.right {
  margin-right: -4%;
  text-shadow: -4px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.slider .buttons button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff5;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.slider .dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider .dots li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.slider .dots li.active {
  width: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .slider {
    height: 400px;
  }
}

.slideMain {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 150%;
  padding: 0.3%;
  background-color: #3A4429;
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
}

.mainSli {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
<body class="baclground">
<div class="call_box">
        <img class="call_butt" draggable="false" src="../images/free-icon-phone-call-455604.png"/>
    </div>
</body>




Как и что должно работать и что с этим сейчас не так? И я вот это слово не понял прогортается

Извините, я сам не говорю на русском, стараюсь как могу. В общем елемент с классом 'call_butt' должен закрепится внизу справа на екране вне зависимости от состояния прокрутки.

https://doka.guide/css/position/#fixed
«Элемент позиционируется относительно окна браузера, за исключением случаев, если один из родителей имеет значения свойств transform, perspective или filter, отличные от none. В этом случае блок становится опорным, и позиционирование будет производиться уже относительно него, а не окна браузера.»

Простите, не совсем понял можете в двух словах описать?(я еще пока все вспоминаю после 3 лет простоя)

Если у какого-то родителя есть transform, то positon:fixed будет отсчитываться от него, а не от окна. И если этот родитель прокручивается в окне, то и спозиционированный элемент будет прокручиваться вместе с ним.

Ага, понял спасибо. Сейчас попробую исправить.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block

Что-то не получается, переместил  в body где есть и так званний header которий остается сверху на екране, а елемент которий нужно все равно нет.

тут и калбокс абсолютный - потому и позиционирование от него. и скролите именно калбокс(ко дну которого и прибит батон) а не страницу. и у тега <body> класс весьма интересный... пока эт всё что заметил.

@puffleeck  потом меняется в js, загрузка страници. А что надо скролить чтоби елемент не скролился?

у тебя для всех элементов, добавляется анимация, в которой transform устанавливается. Если ты ее уберешь - работать стане как нужно. применять анимацию ко всем элемента не лучший выбор

Спасибо, теперь я разобрался в своем же коде(хаха). Спасибо очень еще раз, теперь буду знать. Напишите в ответе, отмечу как правильной).

Как указано в комментариях - если у одного из родительских элементов будет выставлен transform - то position:fixed будет отсчитывать положение в рамках этого элемента.
В коде в вопросе - всем элементам добавляется анимация, в которой устанавливается transform.
Для решения достаточно убрать эту установку из анимации, либо не добавлять эту анимацию для всех элементов
Например:


* {
  font-family: Unageo-Medium;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

body {
  opacity: 0;
}

.background {
  background-color: #BFB9B1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bar {
  transition: none;
  background-color: #3A4429;
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  animation-duration: 0ms;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.bar h3 {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #ddd6ce;
  padding: 1%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}

.bar h3:hover {
  background-color: #687a49;
}

.barMain {
  margin-top: 5%;
  background-color: #3A4429;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.topBar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  nav-up: auto;
  background-color: #3A4429;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 5px 0;
  z-index: 100000;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ddd6ce;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.fixed_down {
  top: 0;
}

.fixed_up {
  top: -75;
}

.topContent {
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  display: flex;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Unageo-Medium";
  src: url(../fonts/Unageo-Medium.ttf);
}

a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  color: #ddd6ce;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mainBody {
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
}

.mainBody1 {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-top: auto;
  padding-bottom: auto;
}

.mainText {
  margin-top: auto;
}

.menuButt {
  align-self: center;
  width: max-content;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #3A4429;
  color: #ddd6ce;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  font-size: x-large;
}

.bottomBar {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3A4429;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.iconBottom {
  width: 30px;
}

.textBottom {
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.boxBottom {
  margin-left: 2%;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 1%;
}

.call_butt {
  background-color: #3A4429;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.call_box {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}


/*Carousel*/

.slider {
  width: 39%;
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 1%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: rotate(2deg);
  border: 4px dashed black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 28px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.slider .list {
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  transition: 1s;
}

.slider .list img {
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: relative;
  object-position: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 114px -19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 114px -19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 114px -19px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)
}

.slider .list span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 5%;
  text-shadow: 4px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition-delay: 2s;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  color: #ddd6ce;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: xx-large;
  z-index: 100;
}

.slider .buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left {
  margin-left: -4%;
  text-shadow: 4px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.right {
  margin-right: -4%;
  text-shadow: -4px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.slider .buttons button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff5;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.slider .dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slider .dots li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.slider .dots li.active {
  width: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .slider {
    height: 400px;
  }
}

.slideMain {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 150%;
  padding: 0.3%;
  background-color: #3A4429;
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
}

.mainSli {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}
<body class="baclground">
  <div class="call_box">
    <img class="call_butt" draggable="false" src="../images/free-icon-phone-call-455604.png" />
  </div>
</body>



